# C++ : Segmentation fault (core dumped) issue

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

**Implementation of [Sieve of eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) in C++ :**

When i Run my C++ program i get

> "Segmentation fault      (core dumped)"

It compiles without any error.

In this program , i am trying to print all prime numbers between two numbers a and b.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX 1000000

using namespace std;

// Print all primes s.t. a <= prime <= b
int main()
{
    int t; // no of test cases
    cin>>t;

    bool prime[MAX + 1];    // a[i] = true for i = prime
    long int count_primes_lte_me[MAX + 1]; // a[i] = Count ( primes ) <= i
    long int counter_of_visited_primes;

    prime[0] = prime[1] = false;
    for(int i = 2 ; i <= MAX ; i++)
    {
        if(prime[i] == true)
            count_primes_lte_me[i] = ++counter_of_visited_primes;

        for(int j = i*i ; j <= MAX ; j += i)  // sieve of eratosthenes
            prime[j] = false;
    }

    long int a , b;
    while(t--)
    {
        cin>>a>>b;
        cout<<count_primes_lte_me[b] - count_primes_lte_me[a - 1]<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just run the program in a debugger or open the core file in a debugger and you'll see where and why it crashes

Comment: `for(int i = 2 ; i <= MAX ; i++)` this is probably wrong

Comment: @EdHeal What's wrong about it?

Comment: It does not look right

Comment: @EdHeal, I still don't understand what's wrong with it. Most sieve implementations I see initially go with the loop approach you highlighted, but then later optimize it to iterate to the sqrt of the limit.

Comment: Most loops have the pattern of `<` no `<=`

Comment: yes , but thats not an issue. personal choice :)

Comment: @EdHeal: It's only "probably wrong" if you don't read the rest of the code.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - good point

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with a smaller value for `MAX`. Allocating such huge arrays on the stack produces the (initial) problem. Then replace with dynamic allocation:

```
bool *prime = new bool[MAX+1];
if (prime==nullptr) // error

...

delete [] prime;
```

You may also use static allocation (define your variables as global).

Best may be to use some appropriate container, for example `bitset`.

**Beware** that `i*i` may overflow, so other problem may arise...

Comment: it works with Small value of max. but i need to run the program with MAX 1000000

Comment: Trying dynamic allocation as u said.. hold on.

Comment: This is about the time when [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) shows up so save the day at the first sign of dynamic arrays. (Sounds corny, I know)

Comment: Dynamic allocation did the job.  Changing to bool *prime = new bool[MAX + 1]; worked. Also changed long *count_primes_lte_me = new long[MAX + 1];

Comment: @ArnavBorborah No your right, time to use some appropriate container...

Comment: Can i also set default values as true while dynamically allocation of prime[]

Comment: Will this work for setting it true .. memset(prime, true, sizeof(prime));

Comment: @JayTeli You could also use [`std::fill_n`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill_n).

Answer (score 1):

`i * i` will overflow in your inner loop for `i <= MAX`. This might cause a segfault due to negative `j`. Use a larger integer type: `long long j = (long long)i * i`.

For correctness, you need to initialize the `prime` array to `true` and the count array to `0` values.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes#Algorithm_and_variants

Comment: @JayTeli what are you trying to tell me?

Comment: Whatever this is actually not the problem, but it is a problem `i*i` may overflow.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès why not? seg fault caused by negative j

Comment: if i * i > MAX then inner for loop condition will fail and  prime[j] wont be accessed.  Also changing inner loop to -> long long j = (long long)i*i .. didnt help.. still getting same runtime error

Comment: @JayTeli no it won't necessarily fail, j can become negative

Comment: @yassin Program crashes before entering the loop.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès ok, I see

Comment: Yes crashes before entering loop

Answer (score 1):

You've a Max of a million... I tried to reduce it and no error but still nothing works... try this

```
/************************************
***Array names as pointers***********
************************************/
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int MAX = 10000;
    long prime[MAX] = { 2, 3, 5 };
    long trial = 5;
    int count = 3;
    int found = 0;

    do
    {
        trial += 2;
        found = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            found = (trial % *(prime + i)/* prime[i] */) == 0;

            if (found)
                break;
        }
        if (found == 0)
            *(prime + count++)/* prime[count++] */ = trial;
    } while (count < MAX);

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
    {
        if (i % 5 == 0)
            cout << endl;
        cout << setw(10) << *(prime + i)/* prime[i] */;
    }
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```